Access Echo devices from different users' apps
This is my first post, I hope I'm in the right place.
Oneliner:  I need help setting up my fiancée's Alexa app to use my Echo device.
Details:  We moved in together and I brought my Echo device with me.
She has gotten used to the voice commands, so we're good there.
But I have other functionality from the app that she'd like to use as well.
Instead of "Alexa, turn on the living room", sometimes I'll do that directly from the app by hitting on the living room smart bulb.
Non-solutions:
i) I had tried this before, and found that I need to sign in with my account on her phone.   I don't like that solution at all.
Alternatively, there's an option of creating a new joint account to use in both phones.
This solution seems to do the trick but doesn't feel like it is technologically sound, as there are so many services that can be shared and not have to create joint accounts to solve.
ii) Setting up profiles in Alexa seems to help for different issues.
That is to open her music instead of mine.  But that doesn't seem to help with operation of controlling the other devices -like lights- from her app.
iii) Another potential solution was to create an Amazon Household, and this isn't supported in my country (Mexico); so unless I'm missing something I don't think I can continue along with it.
So that's what I've come to so far.  Unfortunately I haven't found much in the Amazon website, and that's why I thought to ask this forum.
If someone has come accross this issue and found a nice solution, I'll be grateful for your comments.
Cheers.
